# How to remove compare product icon from new products widget?

Tags: layout, theme, xml, magento2.4, default.xml

As the title asks, how do I remove the "add to compare" button from a "new products" widget? Currently this is what's I'm seeing ... but only within this widget:

[image]

I've got the following XML in my theme's `default.xml` but the compare icon is still visible in the new products widget:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="related.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="upsell.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.list" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Did you run all command after did that?
Please run all commands with di:compile also.

Comment: Yep ran all commands. It's only this one location where it's appearing. It's the "new products" widget so I was thinking maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Find the file of new product widget in the theme and remove compare code from it.

Comment: Surely there's got to be an alternative way to do this than having to override the code.

Comment: You need to find this in theme. And just remove the code.

Answer (score 0):

Open the following list of templates included Luma Magento 2 theme:

```
app\code\Magento\Catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml
app\code\Magento\Catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\widget\new\content\new_grid.phtml
app\code\Magento\Catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\widget\new\content\new_list.phtml
app\code\Magento\CatalogWidget\view\frontend\templates\product\widget\content\grid.phtml
app\code\Magento\Reports\view\frontend\templates\widget\compared\content\compared_grid.phtml
app\code\Magento\Reports\view\frontend\templates\widget\compared\content\compared_list.phtml
app\code\Magento\Reports\view\frontend\templates\widget\viewed\content\viewed_grid.phtml
app\code\Magento\Reports\view\frontend\templates\widget\viewed\content\viewed_list.phtml
```

For each product list block please change

```
$showCompare = true;
```

to

```
$showCompare = false;
```

You can check your phtml file by enabling template path hint .